# localhost:8080 showing a blank page in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have been following this tutorial to set up the environment for developing in react js.

[React - tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-react-fundamentals-development-environment-setup)

But when I run localhost:8080 on browser, it is showing a blank page.
I have tried all the browsers but none of them work.

I have installed webpack, but when I run **webpack** command, it says **output file name not configured**

**My webpack-config.js file**

```
    module.exports = {
   entry: './main.js',

   output: {
      path:'asd/',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },

   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8080
   },

   module: {
      loaders: [ {
         test: /\.js?$/,
         exclude: /node_modules/,
         loader: 'babel',

         query: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react']
         }
      }]
   }

}

module.exports = config;
```

Also,in the tutorial they added a script index.js in the html file which the browser is not able to locate and shows the error

> 404:server could not locate the resource index.js

I start the server from the same path where my folder conatining all the files is located
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

When you run webpack ,it will look the file index.js file in asd folder.please check your folder structure to verify there is a file named indexjs in asd folder.